# Rails: Invalidate cache based on query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, memcached, dalli

I've got query in my Rails application that doesn't take long to run (~180ms), but does return a lot of results. The result is used in an API, and the transformation of the result to JSON is expensive (~3s). To speed things up, I'm caching it like this:

```
key = 'new_prices'
query = Prices.new_this_month.where('...')
json = cache(key, expires_in: 60.minutes) do
  render_to_string json: query, each_serializer: PriceSerializer
end
render json: json
```

In the background, new prices can be added to the database. How can I generate the cache key in such a way that if the result of `query` changes, the cache is invalidated?

I'm using Rails 3.2, with memcached via the `dalli` gem.

Answer (score 0):

As you've got a `new_this_month` scope, I assume `Prices` have a `created_at` timestamp. In that case you could simply use the latest `created_at` in your cache key:

```
cache_key = "new_prices-#{Prices.order('created_at DESC').take.created_at}"
```

If you've got a good database index in place, this should be a very fast query.

Comment: It doesn't actually have a `created_at` date, but one can be deduced. I also think I'm right in saying that the cache won't be invalidated if a price changes? (I don't have a `modified_at`)

Comment: Yes that assumption is correct. You didn't mention this in your question though. There does need to be a way to determine if prices have been updated since the last time the fragment was cached. Otherwise, your only option would be to invalidate the cache manually.